# The keyboard is disabled

Tags: keyboard

When I close my laptop and then open again do, then I can not use my buttons. How do I fix this?

I see my screen but I cannot use the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I've fielded this question a few times over the past few years, and my rule of thumb is to explain that there are many laptops for which it is nearly impossible to install the correct drivers to put it to sleep properly without encountering the problem you describe (or worse).  In such cases your only option is to configure your power settings to do something besides putting the computer to sleep when the lid is closed.

Under "System Settings", "Power", you can select the correct action for what to do when the lid is closed.  Your options should include such choices as, stay on, go to sleep, or shut down.  I never got in the habit of closing my laptop without shutting it down first, so I've never had that problem.